# create a dynamic url into parsed xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I'm new in php.
I'm trying to find a way to match the right url dynamically in every description.
For example in the case where the **description = Xios** i would like the url to become :
`<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Xios">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>`
Now in the case where the **description = Kiklades** i would like the url to become :   `<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Kiklades">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>`
 Endly in the case where the **description = Mikonos** i would like the url to become :
    `<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Mikonos">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>`

```
foreach ($item_array as $item) {
            if ( make_safe($item['diamerisma']) == $_GET['diamerisma'] ) {
                if (!in_array($item['description'], $used_values) ) {//This will check if this value hasn't been listed yet
                    $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
                    $html .= '<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Κυκλάδες">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>';
                    $html .= '</ul>';
                    $html .= '</dd>';
                    $used_values[] = $item['description'];//here you preserve used values for avoiding repetition
                }
            }
        }
```

the xml code

```
    <item>
        <title>Xios center</title>
        <description>Xios</description>
        <diamerisma>Aigaio</diamerisma>
        <metar>1010</metar>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Siros</title>
        <description>Kiklades</description>
        <diamerisma>Aigaio</diamerisma>
        <metar>1011</metar>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Naxos center</title>
        <description>Kiklades</description>
        <diamerisma>Aigaio</diamerisma>
        <metar>1012</metar>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Mikonos center</title>
        <description>Mikonos</description>
        <diamerisma>Aigaio</diamerisma>
        <metar>1013</metar>
    </item>
```

Any help will be appreciated!thanks in advance guys!

Comment: please edit your question and add the code that creates `$item_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know how `$item_array` is created, I'll go back one step from your code and create `$item_array` in a different way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$dia = "Aigaio"; // use $_GET... in your code
$item_array = $xml->xpath("//item[diamerisma = '$dia']");
```

Now, `$item_array` contains only `<item>`-nodes with the desired `<diamerisma>`-child. We do not have to check for `<diamerisma>` in the loop:

```
foreach ($item_array as $item) {

    // simplified
    echo '<a href="main.php?description=' . $item->description . '">' . $item->description . '</a>';    

}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/120611

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is a very simple answer to your question:

```
$html .= '<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=' . make_safe($item['description']) . '">' . make_safe($item['description']) . '</a></div></li>';
```